# PHP: Datetime::Diff results comparison

Tags: php, datetime, comparison, diff

i was trying to compare the difference between 2 dates, but it seems the results are pretty wrong, for example this code:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days')."<br />";

$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-15');
$interval2 = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval2->format('%R%a days')."<br />";

if($interval == $interval2){ echo "true"; }else{echo "false"; }
```

Returns true, but above you can see the date differences are not the same, in fact echo prints +2 and +4. Any idea in how to compare 2 date differences?

EDIT: the datetime::diff returns a dateinterval object, in fact it doesn't implement comparison operators, https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49914
I'll use dateinterval vars to check the difference, thanks for the answers

Comment: object comparison =/= value comparison.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that DateInterval doesn't implement a comparison function internally. Extensions are allowed to define custom comparison rules for their predefined classes. Evidently it falls back to a loose comparison that the objects are of the same class.

[This feature request](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49914) provides a patch to add this functionality in, but it doesn't seem to have made it into the source at any point.

To get around this issue, you can either compare each member variable of your objects yourself (years, months etc.) or you can cast each object to an array:

```
if ((array) $interval == (array) $interval2) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are only [comparing that the two objects<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php) are of the same type (and same value of props), but not that they are identical:

```
if ($interval === $interval2) {echo "true";} else {echo "false";}
              ^^^
```

Take note, that you are doing an object comparison, not a value comparison, like with a string.

Comment: Per [object comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php), objects of the same type with the same public member variables should be considered equal; not sure how reliably this applies to predefined classes though.

Comment: @cbuckley: *"Note: Extensions can define own rules for their objects comparison."* - so everything can happen ;)

Comment: In fact using same date it returns false, check this example http://codepad.viper-7.com/HgUi4v

Comment: @alex88 Using the identity operator, they'll only be identical if they refer to the same instance.

Comment: @alex88: Sure, I mean those objects aren't identical. That's it. You should more specifically compare values, not objects here. Or otherwise know how the object comparison is working for the objects in question. I just wanted to highlight a cause of error.

Comment: @hakre yes you're correct, but the question was in fact how to compare 2 date differences, thank you for your answer, it helped to know what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I have extended the php class. Method compare makes a value comparison. It uses the "natural" order of the variables in php DateInterval class. The foreach cycle goes at first through years, then months, then days, etc. It is probably not a very portable solution, but it seems to be working just fine in php 5.3.

```
/**
 * Description of DateInterval
 *
 * @author Santhos
 */
class DateInterval extends \DateInterval 
{    
    /**
     * compares two date intervals
     * returns:
     *   0 - when they are equal
     *   less than zero - $a is less than $b
     *   greater than zero - $a is greater than $b
     * 
     * @param \Designeo\Utils\DateInterval $dateInterval
     * @return int
     */
    public static function compare($a, $b) 
    {
        // check parameters
        self::isDateInterval($a);
        self::isDateInterval($b);

        foreach ($a as $key => $value) {            
            // after seconds 's' comes 'invert' and other crap we do not care about
            // and it means that the date intervals are the same
            if ($key == 'invert') {                
                return 0;
            }

            // when the values are the same we can move on
            if ($a->$key == $b->$key) {
                continue;
            }

            // finally a level where we see a difference, return accordingly
            if ($a->$key < $b->$key) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private static function isDateInterval($object) 
    {
        if (!is_a($object, 'DateInterval')) {
            throw new \Exception('Parameter dateInterval type has to be a Dateinterval.');
        }
    }

    public function compareToAnother($dateInterval) {
        return self::compare($this, $dateInterval);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning $datetime1->diff($datetime2) both to $interval and $interval2, so they have the exact same values

Comment: You can see that on line 7 i've changed the date ;)

Answer (score 0):

I remember there is a function for comparing the dates in php like this.

```
compare_dates($start_date,$end_date);
```

Comment: Your code is taken from http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php In the same site, you will find the compare_dates syntax here http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Comment: sorry, its not a built in function... apologies !

Answer (score 0):

I made comparison between two DateIntervals using the following way:

```
version_compare(join('.', (array) $dateIntervalA), join('.', (array) $dateIntervalB));
```

Comment: I wouldn't abuse a function that compares version tags for comparing date intervals.