# Weird Behavior When Comparing Datetimes

Tags: php, datetime

My problem is when I uncomment those print_r's the datetime objects are comparing properly.  When I don't print them first they don't compare.  I have literally no idea why printing them first makes them compare properly, or what could be causing this behavior.

```
$difference = $edate->diff($sdate);
$check = date_interval_create_from_date_string('5 days');

//print_r($difference);
//print_r($check);


$data_array = [];

if ($difference < $check) {
     //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: What's the format of $sdate ?

Comment: sdate and edate are DateTimes

Comment: I'm not sure why printing it would change the "data type" of your code, but this might be a related answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724710/php-datetimediff-results-comparison.

Comment: Yea, I get the same result when I var_dump them first too.  Weirdest issue.

Comment: See also : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69587. You also could compare `$difference->f < $check->f`.

Comment: It seems print_r() does odds things https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066034/print-r-adds-properties-to-datetime-objects

Comment: Oops, I misread the question a bit and I think I closed this incorrectly. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is probably a better link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547855/are-php-dateinterval-comparable-like-datetime